# ¿Cómo optimizar mi código y reducir la cantidad de condiciones (if)?

Tags: java

Necesito optimizar mi código. Mi jefe me lo pidió pero no sé cómo hacerlo.

Consideré todas las validaciones posibles, ¿qué quitarían o qué agregarían?

```
public obtenerNum() {
  long numFI = daoF.getNumFI();
  long numFA = daoF.getNumFA();

  if (numFI>=0 && numFA>=0) {
    if (numFI == numFA) {
      if (numFI == 0) {
        return numFI + 1;    
      }
      return numFI  + 1;
    } else if (numFI > numFA) {
      return numFI + 1;
    } else if (numFA > numFI) {
      return numFA + 1;
    } else {
      return -1;
    }
  } else {
    return  -1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Saludos y bienvenido a SOes, por favor en futuras preguntas evita la palabra [ayuda](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4770/palabras-en-t%c3%adtulos-que-pueden-derivar-en-preguntas-de-baja-calidad?cb=1), y espero que sea tu primer dia en el trabajo tratare de explicarte lo que en mi opinion esta mal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hay ciertas zonas de tu código que son innecesarias o se pueden agrupar.

Por ejemplo, esta condición es innecesaria:

```
if (numFI == 0) {
    return numFI + 1;    
}
return numFI + 1;
```

Esta comprobación comprueba si `numFI` vale `0` para devolver el valor `numFI + 1`, que es el mismo valor que hubiera devuelto si no se cumple la condición.

Los dos últimos `else` también se pueden combinar:

```
if (...) {
  if (...) {
    ...
  } else {
    return -1;
  }
} else {
  return -1;
}
```

Aplicando estas dos mejoras podrías reducir tu código a éste:

```
public long obtenerNum() {
  long numFI = daoF.getNumFI();
  long numFA = daoF.getNumFA();

  if (numFI >= 0 && numFA >= 0) {
    if (numFI == numFA) {
      /* Nos ahorramos una condición */
      return numFI + 1;
    } else if (numFI > numFA) {
      return numFI + 1;
    } else if (numFA > numFI) {
      return numFA + 1;
    }
  }
  /* Si la ejecución llega a este punto (los dos else) devolvemos -1 */
  return -1;
}
```

Pero si analizamos el funcionamiento del programa en su conjunto, y no línea a línea, comprenderemos que siempre que `numFI` y `numFA` sean mayores que `0` se devolverá el valor del número más alto más uno.

De modo que podríamos ahorrarnos la mayoría de condiciones calculando el valor mayor, por ejemplo, haciendo uso de [Math.max()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max-long-long-) en vez de hacerlo mediante condiciones `if`:

```
public long obtenerNum() {
  long numFI = daoF.getNumFI();
  long numFA = daoF.getNumFA();

  if (numFI >= 0 && numFA >= 0) {
    return Math.max(numFI, numFA) + 1;
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Por último, recordarte un detalle: necesitas indicar el tipo de dato devuelto por el método de la clase. He editado mi respuesta para agregar el tipo devuelto en mis ejemplos.

Además, puedes probar en línea el correcto funcionamiento del código ([alojado en github](https://github.com/ojgarciab/375540-stackoverflow-es)) usando Gitpod:

[image: Gitpod Ready-to-Code]

Answer (score 0):

Como mencionaron antes hay lugares donde se repiten código.

Por lo que se lee en el código, lo que encesitas es:
Devolver -1 si numFI o numFA son numeros negativos

Esto lo puedes ver en el else de tu primer if

```
if (numFI>=0 && numFA>=0){
    ...
} else {
    return -1;
}
```

Lo que yo te recomendaria seria invertir el primer if. Creando la condicion en la que entra al else anterior. Entonces analizando tu primer if vemos que lo que tu quieres es que *numFI* y *numFA* sean los dos positivos. O sea que si uno de los dos o los dos son negativos entrariamos al else. Y quedaria asi.

```
if(numFI < 0 || numFA <0){
    return -1;
} else {
    ...
}
```

Y luego iriamos a analizar el resto de codigo que tenias en tu primer if.

```
if (numFI == numFA) {
  if (numFI == 0) {
    return numFI + 1;    
  }
  return numFI  + 1;
} else if (numFI > numFA) {
  return numFI + 1;
} else if (numFA > numFI) {
  return numFA + 1;
} else {
  return -1;
}
```

Al analizar este pedazo de codigo, lo que necesitas hacer es devoler el numero entre *numFI* y *numFA* mas alto mas 1. Esto se logra facil on una operacion ternaria. de la siguiente manera.

```
return (numFI > numFA ? numFI : numFA) + 1;
```

Al ser numFI el numero mas grande retornariamos *numFI + 1*. Y si numFI no es el numero mas grande quiere decir que:

- numFA > numFI
- numFA = numFI

En cualquiera de los casos podemos retornar *numFA + 1*. Y agrupando todo tu funcion te quedaria de la siguiente manera.

```
public obtenerNum() {
long numFI = daoF.getNumFI();
long numFA = daoF.getNumFA();

if(numFI < 0 || numFA <0) {
    return  -1;
}

return (numFI > numFA ? numFI : numFA) + 1;
}
```

Si sigues teniendo dudas, sigue preguntando, para eso esta la comunidad y sigue adelante.

Answer (score 0):

creo que la solución de la segunda respuesta es la más eficiente.

Cuando usas la condición IF, el compilador lo evalúa distinto si contiene un OR o un AND. Cuando usas OR, evalúa la primera condición, y si no se cumple, no evalúa la segunda.

En base a este pequeño código, realicé una ejecución, que si la corres en tu equipo podrás ver que efectivamente la segunda solución es más rápida:

````
    public final class Test {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int largoPrueba = 1000;
            int cantidadMuestras = 10000000;
            for (int i = 0; i < largoPrueba; i++) {
                run(cantidadMuestras);
            }

        }

        public static void run(int cantidadMuestras) {
            double[][] datosPrueba = new double[cantidadMuestras][2];
            for (int i = 0; i < cantidadMuestras; i++) {
                datosPrueba[i][0] = Math.random();
                datosPrueba[i][1] = Math.random();
            }
            long inicio;
            long termino;
            long valorO;
            long valor1;
            long valor2;
            long valor3;

            // ORIGINAL.
            inicio = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for (int i = 0; i < cantidadMuestras; i++) {
                obtenerNum(datosPrueba[i][0], datosPrueba[i][1]);
            }
            termino = System.currentTimeMillis();

             valorO = (termino - inicio);

            // R1.
            inicio = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for (int i = 0; i < cantidadMuestras; i++) {
                obtenerNumR1(datosPrueba[i][0], datosPrueba[i][1]);
            }
            termino = System.currentTimeMillis();

            valor1 = (termino - inicio);

            // R2.
            inicio = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for (int i = 0; i < cantidadMuestras; i++) {
                obtenerNumR2(datosPrueba[i][0], datosPrueba[i][1]);
            }
            termino = System.currentTimeMillis();

            valor2 = (termino - inicio);

            // R3.
            inicio = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for (int i = 0; i < cantidadMuestras; i++) {
                obtenerNumR3(datosPrueba[i][0], datosPrueba[i][1]);
            }
            termino = System.currentTimeMillis();

            valor3 = (termino - inicio);

            System.out.println(String.format("%d|%d|%d|%d ", valorO, valor1, valor2, valor3));
        }

        public static double obtenerNum(double numFI, double numFA) {

            if (numFI >= 0 && numFA >= 0) {
                if (numFI == numFA) {
                    if (numFI == 0) {
                        return numFI + 1;
                    }
                    return numFI + 1;
                } else if (numFI > numFA) {
                    return numFI + 1;
                } else if (numFA > numFI) {
                return numFA + 1;
                } else {
                    return -1;
                }
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        }

        public static double obtenerNumR1(double numFI, double numFA) {
            if (numFI >= 0 && numFA >= 0) {
                return Math.max(numFI, numFA) + 1;
            }
            return -1d;
        }

        public static double obtenerNumR2(double numFI, double numFA) {
            if (numFI < 0 || numFA < 0) {
                return -1;
            }
            return (numFI > numFA ? numFI : numFA) + 1d;
        }

        public static double obtenerNumR3(double numFI, double numFA) {
            if (0 > numFI || 0 > numFA) {
                return -1;
            }
            return (numFI > numFA ? numFI : numFA) + 1d;
        }
    }
```
Según la ejecución de este test -bastante primitivo- el promedio de tiempo (en segundos) de ejecución es más menos:

Solución Original = 62
Respuesta 1 = 18
Respuesta 2 = 9
Propuesta mía = 13 

Espero te sirva mi respuesta.
````

Comment: Me parece que es _si se cumple, no evalúa la segunda_. _Si no se cumple, no evalúa la segunda_, correspondería a un _and_. Referencia: las respuestas a [esta pregunta (en inglés)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8759868)

Comment: Y por cierto, pon un enlace a "la segunda" pregunta, porque hay más de un criterio de orden para las respuestas :) No está demás que hagas el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.